# Merge multiple txt in several subdirectories into 1 txt for each subdirectories in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, merge, txt

OS : Windows 10

Here are example directory structure.

```
D:\Fruits\Apple\ a.txt k.txt c.txt

D:\Fruits\Mango\ g.txt q.txt b.txt
```

I want to merge txt file for each folder like this.

```
D:\Fruits\Apple\ a.txt k.txt c.txt merge.txt (a+k+c)

D:\Fruits\Mango\ g.txt q.txt b.txt merge.txt (g+q+b)
```

@echo off

for /r " D:\Fruits" %%a in (*.txt) do type "%%a" >>"merge.txt"

I tried this batch but the result is not my expected.

```
D:\Fruits\merge.txt (a+k+c+g+q+b)
```

Please help me how to proceed on the task. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop if you're not doing this recursively, just `Type "D:\Fruits\*.txt" 1>"merge.txt"` should do. Also you could do it with the `Copy` command, `Copy "D:\Fruits\*.txt" "merge.txt"`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?` to read its usage information, and similarly `type /?` to learn how the other command works. If you are wanting to do this recursively, then you will need the `for` loop sequence, however, I'd still advise you use a `For /F` loop, _(`for /?`)_.

Comment: You also need to be aware, that if you intend the merged text file results to be located in each of the subdirectories in which their respective source files lie, then you may want to reconsider naming the result file with the same extension. If you don't it will try to include itself in its own results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`for /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to loop through the directories, then process each of them individually, using [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to retrieve all `*.txt` files, [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to exclude the result file `merge.txt` and [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to iterate through the files. To eventually write `merge.txt`, use [output redirection `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
for /D %%J in ("D:\Fruits\*") do (
    > "%%~J\merge.txt" (
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
            dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "%%~J\*.txt" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"merge.txt"
        ') do (
            type "%%~J\%%I"
        )
    )
)
```

Instead of [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) to write the result file, [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) can be used also:

```cmd
for /D %%J in ("D:\Fruits\*") do (
    > "%%~J\merge.txt" rem/ // deplete the file in advance;
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('
        dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:N "%%~J\*.txt" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"merge.txt"
    ') do (
        copy /B "%%~J\merge.txt" + "%%~J\%%I" "%%~J\merge.txt"
    )
)
```

The `*.txt` files are merged in alphabetical order due to the `/O:N` of the `dir` command.